# f in L^1 implies lim f(x+n) = 0 for a.e. x

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that for almost every $x \in [0,1]$, the sequence $\{f(x+n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$.

I am trying to use the fact that $f(x+n)= \frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x+n} f(y) \ dy$. But how do I justify the exchange of limit and derivative on the RHS ?

Can anyone provide a useful hint ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ \int_{[0,1)} (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|f(x+n)|)\ dx =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{[0,1)} |f(x+n)|\ dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{[n,n+1)} |f(x)|\ dx = \int_0^\infty |f| <\infty.$$

Comment: I am able to prove that for almost all $z \in [x,x+1]$ the above result that $f(z+n) \rightarrow 0$ is true where $x$ can be arbitrarily small. Is that correct ?