# Does $f(x + n)$ go to zero for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ integrable.

Tags: calculus, limits, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$. Is it true, that for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x + n) = 0?$$

I was already able to prove that we have

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[n, n+1]} f(x) \,d\mu(x) = 0$$

(using dominated convergence). How can I proceed from here?

Comment: I'm not sure that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[n,n+1]} f(x)\,d\mu(x) = 0$ helps. But $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{[n,n+1]} \lvert f(x)\rvert\,d\mu(x) < \infty$$ helps.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532581, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2528240.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! This helps indeed.